# Why doesn't "export" overwrite existing values?

Tags: path, command, variable, which

Why isn't `export python=/usr/local/bin/python2.7` changing the path to `python`?

I am baffled by the following:

```
$ which python
/usr/bin/python
$ export python=/usr/local/bin/python2.7
$ which python
/usr/bin/python
```

I'm using OSX v10.12.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The program `which` determines the path of shell commands.

What you did in the second statement is set a variable named `python`.

Shell commands and variables are entirely different things.

What you'd might like to use is an alias.

```
alias python="/usr/local/bin/python2.7"
```

Note, that  (except in `zsh` or `tcsh`, or if your `which` is itself a shell function that invokes GNU `which`, as recommended by its manual), `which` will not show the alias, while e.g. `type python` will.

Comment: Additionally, `/usr/bin/python` is probably a symbolic link to the system's version of python. Alternatively they could change the link to point to the version of python they wish to use. After verifying it really is a link and backing it up just in case of course.